# Preventing aggregated rows of total invoice volumes when using GROUPBY to find percentage of paid invoices

Tags: t-sql, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to determine the total amount of partial payment instances made to a single invoice total, but when I do the INNER JOIN to calculate the partial payments, T-SQL automatically aggregates each invoice amount for each partial payment made towards it, skewing the invoice totals. It's not throwing any errors, but I've tried everything I can think of, so if anyone has any helpful advice on how to approach this, it'd be much appreciated!

```
    DECLARE @StartYear INT 
SET @StartYear = '2014'

DECLARE @EndYear INT 
SET @EndYear = '2018'

SELECT 
COUNT(i.InvoiceKey) AS InvoiceKey, 
ISNULL(YEAR(p.TransPostDate), @StartYear) AS PaymentYear, 
SUM(i.Amt) AS InvoiceAmount,
SUM(p.Amt) AS PartialPaymentsTotalsAmount
FROM .[Invoices] i
INNER JOIN [Payments] p ON i.InvoiceKey = p.InvoiceKey
WHERE i.ClientKey = '518' 
AND p.InvClientKey = '518'
AND i.CloseDate IS NULL 
AND (p.TransPostDate IS NOT NULL OR ((YEAR(p.TransPostDate) * 100)) BETWEEN ((@StartYear * 100)) AND ((@EndYear * 100)) )
GROUP BY i.InvoiceKey, YEAR(p.TransPostDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(p.TransPostDate) ASC;
```

Comment: Please post some sample data with the incorrect results and the desired results - ideally using SQL someone can copy and paste. Also it may help to tag the actual database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you sum of the number of payments made that were less than the invoice total. You can use a CASE statement within a COUNT to achieve this. I also simplified your code a bit:

```
declare @StartYear int  = '2014';
declare @EndYear int = '2018';

select count(i.InvoiceKey) as [Number of Payments made on Invoice]
       -- this will never by null because of the WHERE clause
      ,year(p.TransPostDate) as PaymentYear
       -- I assume multiple payments to one invoice, so don't want to sum here.
       -- All values are the same, just take the MAX. MIN would work too.
      ,max(i.Amt) as [Invoice Amount]
      ,sum(p.Amt) as [Total Payment Made]
       -- count of partial payments
      ,count(case when p.Amt < i.Amt then i.InvoiceKey end) [Number of partial payments made]
       -- sum of partial payments
      ,sum(case when p.Amt < i.Amt then p.Amt end) [Sum of partial payments made]
from.[Invoices] i
inner join [Payments] p
on i.InvoiceKey = p.InvoiceKey
where i.ClientKey = '518'
      and p.InvClientKey = '518'
      and i.CloseDate is null
      -- if this is not true, then by definition p.TransPostDate is not null so
      -- you don't need to specify "p.TransPostDate IS NOT NULL".
      -- There is no need to multiply by 100
      and year(p.TransPostDate) between @StartYear and @EndYear
group by i.InvoiceKey
        ,year(p.TransPostDate)
order by year(p.TransPostDate) asc;
```

Comment: Thanks! So I'm using a DATEPART to split the transpost date field associated with each partial payment into a general year, but there are instances of multiple payments that could span across a year or two, sometimes as many as 3-4-5 payments, which automatically aggregate the invoice totals each partial payment is linked to. i'm not looking for partial payments to equal the total invoice amount, because that's not the exercise...

Comment: I'm confused as to the result set you are looking for. An example dataset and expected result set would be helpful. But, you can probably use a CASE inside the MAX(i.Amt) clause to have that value be NULL for all but one record.